# Make select controls visible based on selected tab using xaml

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've got following code:

```
    private Dictionary<int, UserControl> tabControls = new Dictionary<int, UserControl>();

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        tabControls[0] = new Panel1();
        tabControls[1] = new Panel2();
        tabControls[2] = new Panel3();
        tabControls[3] = new Panel4();
        tabControls[4] = new Panel5();
        tabControls[5] = new Panel6();
        tabControls[6] = new Panel7();
        tabControls[7] = new Panel8();
    }

    public object SelectedTab
    {
        //this is assigned from xaml binding
        set
        {
            OnCurrentTabChanged(tabControl.SelectedIndex);
        }
    }


    void OnCurrentTabChanged(int tabIndex)
    {
        if (dataDisplay != null)
        {
            dataDisplay.Children.Clear();
            dataDisplay.Children.Add(tabControls[tabIndex]);
        }
    }
```

Every time the user selects different tab, an other control appears.

Is there any way to simplify this using xaml?

I cannot put the controls themselves inside the tab control

Comment: What's wrong with adding `<TabItem>`s to your `<TabControl>`? You could put the panels inside tab items, and the inactive ones will hide when a different tab is selected. Am I missing something?..

Answer (score 2):

I've done this before with another `TabControl` which has it's headers and frame hidden. Then I just bind the `SelectedIndex` to your other tab's `SelectedIndex`, and the two are synchronized

```
<!-- TabControl without the TabHeaders -->
<Style x:Key="TabControl_NoHeadersStyle" TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
    <Setter Property="SnapsToDevicePixels" Value="true"/>
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type TabControl}">
                <DockPanel>
                    <!-- This is needed to draw TabControls with Bound items -->
                    <StackPanel IsItemsHost="True" Height="0" Width="0" />

                    <ContentPresenter x:Name="PART_SelectedContentHost"
                                      ContentSource="SelectedContent" />
                </DockPanel>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Then you can setup your two tab controls, each bound to different sources, and bind the `SelectedIndex` of one to the `SelectedIndex` of the other

```
<TabControl x:Name="MainTabControl" />

<TabControl ItemsSource="{Binding Panels}"
            SelectedIndex="{Binding ElementName=MainTabControl, Path=SelectedIndex}" 
            Style="{StaticResource TabControl_NoHeadersStyle}" />
```

Another alternative is to bind the `SelectedIndex` to something in your code-behind, then anytime it changes, raise a `PropertyChanged` notification on another property that exposes the panel you want to display.

```
<TabControl SelectedIndex="{Binding SelectedTabIndex} />

<ContentControl Content="{Binding SelectedPanel}" />
```

and in the code behind

```
public int SelectedTabIndex
{
    get { return _selectedTabIndex;}
    set
    {
        if (_selectedTabIndex != value)
        {
            _selectedTabIndex = value;
            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedTabIndex");

            RaisePropertyChanged("SelectedPanel");
        }
    }
}

public UserControl SelectedPanel
{
    get { return tabControls[SelectedTabIndex]; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

TabItem has an IsSelected propery you could bind to that I think would simplify the syntax.

```
 public bool TabIsSelected
 {
     get { return tabIsSelected; }
     set 
     {
          if (value && dataDisplay != null)
          {
              dataDisplay.Children.Clear();
              dataDisplay.Children.Add(tabControls[tabIndex]);
          }
          tabIsSelected = value;
     }
```

But I still don't get why you can't just put the control in the tabitem?

Answer (score 0):

using codebehind

```
void OnCurrentTabChanged(int tabIndex)
{
    if (dataDisplay != null)
    {
        UIElemnt[] pp = dataDisplay.Children.Cast<UIElement>().ToArray();
        Array.ForEach(pp, x=> x.visibility = Visibility.Collapsed); 
        pp[tabIndex].visibility = Visibility.Visible;
    }
}
```

Comment: -1 "I cannot put the controls themselves inside the tab control" ... you assume them added and just swap visibility.